# ESLint: '.map is missing in props validation' (eslint react/prop-types) in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

First time posting!

I'm using Typescript with React to make a small project. I'm having an issue with ESLint not recognizing that a prop variable with the type `string[]` would normally have a .map function because its an array.

App.tsx

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [ingredientsList, setIngredientsList] = useState<string[]>([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Route path="/" exact render={() => <IngredientListSearch ingredientsList={ingredientsList} setIngredientsList={setIngredientsList} />} />
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in my IngredientListSearch.tsx

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// ... bootstrap imports

type Props = {
  ingredientsList: string[]
  setIngredientsList: (arr: string[]) => void
}

function IngredientListSearch({ ingredientsList, setIngredientsList }: Props) {
  // state hooks
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState<string>('');

  // ... miscellaneous logic functions
  
  // function with error in question
  function makeIngredientItems() {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Included Ingredients:</p>
        <ListGroup variant="flush">
          // piece of code in question
          {ingredientsList.map((name, index) => (
            <ListGroup.Item key={index} variant="info">
              // ... Item details here
            </ListGroup.Item>
          ))}
        </ListGroup>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      //... html elements that work fine
      
      <div className="ingredient-list-container">
        {
          ingredientsList.length === 0
            ? <p>Add some Ingredients to get started!</p>
            : makeIngredientItems()
        }
        </div>
        <div />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default IngredientListSearch;
```

ESLint will throw me an error with the message `'ingredientsList.map' is missing in props validation (eslint react/prop-types)`

I'm not really sure what the issue is, I would appreciate any help I can get!

Edit:

Adding an `IngredientListSearch.propTypes` to the bottom of the file in conjunction with my Props use solved my linter error like so.

```js
type Props = {
  ingredientsList: string[],
  setIngredientsList: (arr: string[]) => void
}

function IngredientListSearch({ ingredientsList, setIngredientsList }: Props) {
//... component
}

IngredientListSearch.propTypes = {
  ingredientsList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
  setIngredientsList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

But it didn't make sense to me to be using both propTypes and Typescript. I understand Typescript only type checks at compile while propTypes checks at runtime, but I don't believe both are necessary.

My project works just fine declaring a Prop type with Typescript, and its just the ESlinter yelling at me. I'm going to just remove the `react/prop-types` rule and continue to use `type Props`.

Comment: Maybe you can use this example to submit an issue to the `eslint-plugin-react` repo. It looks like a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define type of prop like this:

```
IngredientListSearch.propTypes = {
  ingredientsList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)
}
```

The `props` is a plain object. If you want to iterate over it add a proper prop-type check.

Comment: What's the Difference between this and defining Props like I did before? I explicitly state IngredientsList is to be of a type string[], then I destructure the props object to extract it.

Comment: this isn't right, it should be `IngredientListSearch.propTypes`, not `.Props`

Comment: anyway, according to https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md the typescript version should work!

Comment: @edwinramos this is the correct usage without warnings

Comment: @SantiagoV. using my type Props as is but including an IngredientsListSearch.propType at the bottom of the file, puts me in the clear but it seems counterintuitive to declare the same information twice. is there a way around this ?

Comment: you can safely remove Props declaration.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain if I remove the Props declaration, typescript tells me my props have an implicit type of any.

Comment: thank you both for your clarification and inputs, I decided i'm going to disable the linter rule as it doesn't make sense to adhere to it in my use case. You can read my edit on the original posting for clarification. thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

*In your .eslintrc or .eslintrc.js, add the next line in rule section (in my case is .eslintrc):*

```
"rules": {
  // other rules
  "react/prop-types" : "off",
}
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, but it avoids the feature entirely