# React: '.map is missing in props validation' in Typescript Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error in Lint for a Typescript function component. How can I fix?

> paymentListData.map' is missing in props validation ,
> also getting something similar for paymentListData.length

```
type Props = {
  paymentListData: PaymentState[];
};


const PaymentList = ({
  paymentListData
}: Props) => {

   return (
    <Box>
       {paymentListData?.map(payment => (
        <PaymentCollectedRow
           key={payment.paymentId}
           patientId={patientId}
           serviceLocationGuid={serviceLocationGuid}
           payment={payment}
           receiptRequest={receiptRequest}
         />
     ))}
```

The solutions in stackoverflow are for Classes, not Typescript Functions.

[ESLint: '.map is missing in props validation' (eslint react/prop-types) in Typescript React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037619/eslint-map-is-missing-in-props-validation-eslint-react-prop-types-in-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `PropTypes` checks on the functional components as you would in classes.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

function HelloWorldComponent({ name }) {
  return (
    <div>Hello, {name}</div>
  )
}

HelloWorldComponent.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
}

export default HelloWorldComponent
```

You can check the docs here -> https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html